# Non IKEA dishwasher for IKEA Metod system

Tags: kitchens, dishwasher

I have a kitchen finished with IKEA Metod system and a narrow, 45 cm wide non-IKEA dishwasher. Apparently the IKEA dishwasher front does not fit the typical dishwasher - Metod front's dimensions are 45x80 cm, while recommended ones for a typical dishwasher are 45x(71 - 75) cm. If you follow the dishwasher's manual and mount the Metod front on in, you will not be able to open it (see the image).
[image: Dishwaser]

There are two recommended solutions:

- cut the IKEA front in two pieces and mount them in a way where one is static and the other one is attached to the door. I don't want to do it due to aesthetics.
- replace dishwasher with IKEA one - they have a sophisticated hinge system where front slides up while opening door. I would like to avoid this solution if possible, because IKEA's dishwasher is very expensive and really noisy in compare with competition.

I tried my luck with a DIY solution using drawer slides - I attached them to the dishwasher and front. I had to pull up the door while opening and it was kind of working. The biggest issue was that you had to be aware of it - if you didn't pull up and hit the bottom of dishwasher like in the middle picture, you would destroy the "construction". It happened twice. Recently, after the third assembly since October, one slide bent and it all fell apart. I gave up this solution.

I have a second flat which I want to decorate and rent. I am prepared to do "dishwasher transplantation" and get myself a new one. The question is:

**Do you have an experience in non-ikea dishwasher with IKEA Metod system? If so, how should I mount a Metod front on a 45 cm non-IKEA dishwasher?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news - Ikea came up with the solution by itself. Recently (about one week ago here in Poland) they've released a hinge system that supports all non-ikea dishwasher. It's based on a sliders which you attach to the front of dishwasher. It costs around 22 euro and works like magic :)

---

Iggy, Dmoore, thank you for your answers.

Iggy, removing bottom kick plate didn't work because front panel hit the extendable legs which obviously couldn't be removed.

DMoore, this solution might work but it's quite pricy - around 1/4 of a dishwasher.

Comment: Please can you be more specific. What is the solution? I have Hotpoint dishwasher and I have the same problem.

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I'm pretty sure the hinge system was named BEHJALPLIG.

Comment: But they have stopped to build that and that is not a good solution. Because after some times the hinges become so hard .. I believe the the best solution is to ask the kitchen fitter to fit the door accordingly and make sure while fitting the door can be open 90 degree.

Comment: There is now an IKEA product called "ERSÄTTARE Sliding-hinge f semi int dishwasher" for 17GBP which I think I will have to use.

Comment: I've now realised that ERSÄTTARE only works when you have a 4-panel door (made of drawer fronts). It doesnt work with a single solid door. https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/ersaettare-sliding-hinge-f-semi-int-dishwasher-00250664/ (Kitchen project delayed 2 years by builders!!)

Answer (score 1):

My team ordered [this](https://www.adapt-r.nl/en/) when we did two houses in France a couple years ago.  I did not personally use it, but it worked.

Comment: DMoore, can you please provide the name of this hinge system?

Answer (score 0):

Metod doesn't seem to off this width is shorter panels. So, I think your only real option would be to remove the dishwasher's bottom kick-plate & see if the panel operates without hitting any dishwasher components.

Cutting out kick-plate mounts is fine, as long as it swings clear of everything else, then you could add side fillers to the cabinet sides, not the dishwasher panel, to hide the unsightly gap.

Just so you're aware. With the full panel on your dishwasher you will need to completely slide out the dishwasher for any & all future servicing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to simply keep the dishwasher close to the floor, most dishwashers that are fully integrated are about 820mm high (Ikea cabinetry 880mm high), you can then install a 50-60mm filler between the dishwasher and floor and then when you install the Ikea dishwasher door you fit it 50-60mm higher so it does not dig into the machine base when you open the dishwasher.

Comment: I think you mean to put the filler up top (between the dishwasher and countertop), so you _can_ mount the door higher.

Answer (score 0):

As grzebyk writes, Ikea have a kit you can mount the door with. It's name is BEHJÄLPLIG (part number 502.913.70). It can be a bit hard to get hold of. In my local market, they didn't advertise it online, but asking for it in-store they had it in stock, so try that. The price is around 20 EUR, so not bad.

The bad news is that it's a crappy solution. If you drop the door too early, the combined weight of the dishwasher door and you mounted Ikea front will cause enough momentum to creak the small plastic hinges that carries the entire weight. I decided to have a replacement 3d-printed. Presumably the 3d-printed plastic is very tough, so that may be enough, but otherwise it's also possible to have one printed in steel, which will be my backup plan.

Link, in case you want to try the same:
https://www.shapeways.com/product/QKLLDFTAT/ikea-behjalplig-128750-a